# audio trimmer in mobile view using HTML5

Tags: html, html5-audio, audio-recording

I tried this code for mouse event,to select audio to trim. I need to trim audio in mobile touch event. how to select audio section in mobile touch event?

```
this.canvasReference.onmousedown = function(e)
{
this.eventHost.mouseDown = true;
console.log("Setexample :123" );

if (this.eventHost.movementActive == false)
{
    var selectionStartPixel = this.eventHost.getAbsoluteToPixel(this.eventHost.selectionStart);
    var selectionEndPixel = this.eventHost.getAbsoluteToPixel(this.eventHost.selectionEnd);

    // is the mouse inside of the selection right now
    if (this.eventHost.mouseX - 5 > selectionStartPixel &&
        this.eventHost.mouseX + 5 < selectionEndPixel)
    {
        this.eventHost.mouseInsideOfSelection = true;
    }
    // is the mouse on the left bar of the selection
    else if (this.eventHost.mouseX - 5 < selectionStartPixel &&
             this.eventHost.mouseX + 5 > selectionStartPixel)
    {
        this.eventHost.mouseSelectionOfStart = true;
    }
    // is the mouse on the right bar of the selection
    else if (this.eventHost.mouseX - 5 < selectionEndPixel &&
             this.eventHost.mouseX + 5 > selectionEndPixel)
    {
        this.eventHost.mouseSelectionOfEnd = true;
    }
    // if the mouse is somewhere else, start a new selection
    else
    {
        this.eventHost.selectionStart = this.eventHost.getPixelToAbsolute(this.eventHost.mouseX);
        this.eventHost.selectionEnd = this.eventHost.selectionStart;
        console.log("Set " + this.eventHost.selectionStart);
    }
}
// get the focus on this editor
focusOnAudioLayerSequenceEditor = this.eventHost;
this.eventHost.repaint();
this.eventHost.updateSelectionForLinkedEditors();
};
```

Selection area like,
[trimming output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VIRH.png)